# Finding a vector orthogonal to columns of a matrix.

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

Given a matrix $X$ of sixe $n\times m$ with $m>n$ or $m<n$ how to find a vector orthogonal to all the $m$ columns of $X$ in the most computationally efficiemt way.

Answer (score 1):

Such a vector is a solution of $X^T x = 0$, so...